# Sometime we declare scalar variable with in parenthesis, can someone let me know what does it mean?

Tags: perl

when we declare a scalar in parenthesis in Perl what does it mean actually?

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my ($x)=10;
print "$x";
```

Comment: This is about the one of **most** important aspects of perl called **context**. If you could obtain a book: _Learning perl (6th edition)_ read chapter starting on page 55: called as _Scalar and List Context_.

Answer (score 4):

It forces the right operand of the assignment to be evaluated in list context. It's useless in your example (because `10` doesn't care about context), but it matters in other situations.

```
my @a = qw( a b c );

my $count = @a;           # 3
my ($first_val) = @a;     # a
```

For details, see [Mini-Tutorial: Scalar vs List Assignment Operator](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different uses for this. One that is pretty common is to declare multiple vars in one line.

```
my ($a, $b, $c);
```

You can also use it to assign vars to array index values

```
my ($a, $b, $c) = @letters
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the two existing answers, it's also worth noting that `my` is a very few case of a Perl keyword that needs parenthesis in some cases, just like `if` and `for` do.

You need the parens if you want to declare more than one variable at the same time.

```
my $foo, $bar; # only declares $foo, will fail under strict if $bar is not there
my ( $foo, $bar); # works
```

Using it with parenthesis is also useful if you want assign the return values of a function to new variables, but you don't care about some of them.

```
my ( undef, $min, $hour) = localtime;
```

In this example with [`localtime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html), the first return value *seconds* is ignored. All the other values (`$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst`) are also ignored, because we never assign them.

Comment: @ikegami it is under `use strict` if `$bar` has not been declared before. It also [throws a warning](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html#Parentheses-missing-around-%22%25s%22-list) under `use warnings` about missing parenthesis.

Comment: @ikegami see the update. that should be better. I'm getting the warning in 5.20.1, and it's still in perldiag in 5.24.1